# What is the difference between surface structure and logical form?

Tags: syntax, theoretical-linguistics

I'm still confused about the difference between these two concepts. Could you explain it with some examples? Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: This question is broad enough to be answered in textbook chapters or even whole books, not a few sentences in a Stack Exchange post. Which textbook are you using for your class? Have you checked there? If yes, what specifically are you unsure about?

Comment: An answer to the question can be found in e.g. H. de Svart "Introduction to natural language semantics" ch. 5, J. Lyons "Linguistic semantics" ch. 7.3, or  E. Zimmermann & W. Sternefeld "Introduction to semantics" ch. 3.4.

Comment: @lemontree♦ Thank you for your kind reply! Actually I'm reading Chapter 4 Case of HNG. Understanding Minimalism, but it's too overwhelming to me. I'll check out what you recommended. I'm really appreciative! :)

Comment: If you want to come more from the syntactic side, you could also give S. Müller "[Grammatical Theory](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/287)" ch. 3.1.3, A. Carnie "Sytax: A Generative Introduction" ch. 12 .2-12.3, L. Haegman "Introduction to Government and Binding Theory" ch. 9 or A. Radford et. al. "Linguistics: An Introduction" ch. 23 a try.

Comment: @lemontree♦ That's so considerate of you! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are special terminology from the **Y model**.

```
  DS
   | (overt movement)
  SS
 / | (covert movement)
PF LF
```

Today it is more common to draw a kind of **T model**.

```
     |
     |
LF __SO__ PF
```

No Deep Structure (DS) in the T model. Surface Structure is nowadays called Spell-out and is rather a point in the derivation (a point in time) than a representational level. There is "before" and "after Spell-out" rather than "at Surface Structure".

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add examples for you. Quantifier raising for example can be analyzed as  being the difference between what you hear (aka Surface Structure) and LF.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply!:) Now I get it!

Comment: You're welcome -- see also this answer https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/6016/4904 about "base generation" -- very much related.